# Converting a Python file into a desktop application

Tags: python, macos, pygame, pycharm

I've coded a game in **Pygame** using **Pycharm**, and I want to make it into a downloadable desktop application so that other people can download and use it even if they do not have python or the necessary files. The problem is I don't know how to. I've heard of **py2exe** and **py2app** before. I tried **py2exe** but then realized that **.exe** was for **windows**, and I was using a **Mac**. I read the **py2app** documentation, but it was very confusing and hard to understand, and none of the things they said worked. They said to use the pip command to install **py2app** inside the terminal, but I tried it and it said that it did not recognize the pip command. Can someone please help? Thanks!
Sorry if this question is long. I am trying to tell as much information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyinstaller if you package the application in Mac OS it will run on Mac.

Click [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/)  for instruction on how to install the package and use it.

Comment: i cant install it it says the same error when I use pip and when I install the file chrome blocks it

Answer (score 0):

Which installation of Python do you use? I had bad experience with `Homebrew` when it came to packaging, then I've removed it and switched to Python3.9 downloaded directly from [python.org](https://www.python.org/) and everything works well now.

Depending on your Python installation, it is possible that you don't have `pip` installed on your computer. Via terminal, you can check it using

```
python -m pip --version
```

and you should get a response of this type:

```
pip X.Y.Z from .../site-packages/pip (python X.Y)
```

If you don't have `pip`, you can either re-install Python as mentioned above, or you can just install `pip` using [these instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

As soon as you have `pip` installed, you can install `py2app` using

```
pip install py2app
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. there is a problem, though. When I type the code into the terminal, it says syntax error. I don't know a lot about pip, so I don't know if it is right or not.By the way,  I am using pycharm, with a Python 3.9 interpreter.

Comment: Do you mean you get `syntax error` after typing `python -m pip --version`? You should either get a response as mentioned above, or `No module named pip` in case `pip` is not installed. How did you installed Python 3.9?

Comment: If you keep getting `syntax error`, please copy & paste here the exact command you have used. It can have a simple reason such as a missing character (e.g., there are _two_ hyphens before `version` in `python -m pip --version`).

Comment: ok, I will try again. thank you for your patience.

Comment: oh ok it says no module named pip i was looking at another terminal lol sry about that

Comment: No problem, we are here to help :) I've started myself with Mac just 4 months ago and had to learn everything about packaging, code signing etc. Finding good information is not always easy.

Comment: OK, so `pip` is not installed. Which installation of Python have you used? For me, it worked best to remove the installation that I had at that moment (which was `homebrew`) and to install Python from `python.org` as mentioned above. I'm combining it with Anaconda (which only came with Python 3.8 at that moment) because I like how `conda` works with virtual environments. Further, I'm also using PyCharm.

Comment: Yes, I have understood you are using PyCharm. But PyCharm is an IDE, not a Python installation. What Python installation do you use? Or, in other words, how did you install your Python? For example, via Anaconda? Or directly from python.org? Or via `homebrew`?

Comment: i installed python from python.org

Comment: i think there is still an error though I tried again it says bash command not found

Comment: If you have installed Python directly from python.org, it should include `pip` so calling pip should be no problem. Once again, please copy & paste here the exact command you have used and the exact error message you have got, otherwise it's very difficult to guess what happens.

Comment: i tried typing it into the terminal again and it just says syntax error. for some reason it highlights the "I" in install in red.

Comment: Have you typed 'install' with capital 'I'? If yes, that would be the reason.

Comment: @RayTang If you need further help, please either post a screenshot clearly showing what precisely you have entered and what was the response (preferably in this case), or copy/paste both the command you have used and the whole response.